# PHP strtotime to get the last day of a given year

Tags: php

How can i get the last day of a year passed as parameter using strtotime?

I try this but the results are not the correct last days :

```
$yearEnd2015 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december this year -3'));
    $yearEnd2016 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december this year -2'));
    $yearEnd2017 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december this year -1'));
    $yearEnd     = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december this year'));

    echo " <br>2015 : ".$yearEnd2015;
    echo " <br>2016 : ".$yearEnd2016;
    echo " <br>2017 : ".$yearEnd2017;
    echo " <br>2018 : ".$yearEnd;
```

Comment: You want the date or the name of the day?

Comment: It's always going to be December 31st…!?

Comment: i was looking for the date but i realize this is always 31 . How can i get the name of the day ?

Comment: [Use `l`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: You could use date() -> `echo date("D", strtotime("$year/12/31"));` // set your year variable, output for 2017: Sun

Comment: thank you! it solves the problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, just send the last day in the year(31 Dec) to the `strtotime` function, for example to get the date name of the last day in 2015:

```
$yearEnd2015 = date('l', strtotime('2015-12-31'));
echo $yearEnd2015;
```

Or you can store the desired year in a variable(if you want to use it in a function or the year changes dynamically): for example to get all the last date names from 2000 till now:

```
$year = 2000;
while($year++ <= 2018) {
  $yearEnd = date('l', strtotime($year . '-12-31'));
  echo $yearEnd . '<br />';
}
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Yes this answer helps me a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

i think you get year from user input . u refer this one

```
$lastdate="-12-31";
$year=$_POST['year'];//lets say you get yearr from post
$day=date('l',strtotime($year.$lastdate));
echo $day;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need strtotime (even though you could definitely use it). If you get the year as an input parameter:

```
$year = '2018';
$lastday = date($year.'-12-31');
echo $lastday;
```

This is a simple hack that only works because you're actually building the same calendar date and only changing the year. But does the trick for what you need

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('l',strtotime(date('Y')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write code like this

```
$yearEnd2015 = date('Y-m-d D', strtotime('2015-12-31'));
$yearEnd2016 = date('Y-m-d D', strtotime('2016-12-31'));
$yearEnd2017 = date('Y-m-d D', strtotime('2017-12-31'));
$yearEnd     = date('Y-m-d D', strtotime('2018-12-31'));

echo " <br>2015 : ".$yearEnd2015;
echo " <br>2016 : ".$yearEnd2016;
echo " <br>2017 : ".$yearEnd2017;
echo " <br>2018 : ".$yearEnd;
```